# UIImage slicing causing crash

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am using the following code to cut image to tiles and place each in a collection:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
  func image(withRotation radians: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let cgImage = self.cgImage!
    let LARGEST_SIZE = CGFloat(max(self.size.width, self.size.height))
    let context = CGContext.init(data: nil, width:Int(LARGEST_SIZE), height:Int(LARGEST_SIZE), bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: cgImage.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: cgImage.bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

    var drawRect = CGRect.zero
    drawRect.size = self.size
    let drawOrigin = CGPoint(x: (LARGEST_SIZE - self.size.width) * 0.5,y: (LARGEST_SIZE - self.size.height) * 0.5)
    drawRect.origin = drawOrigin
    var tf = CGAffineTransform.identity
    tf = tf.translatedBy(x: LARGEST_SIZE * 0.5, y: LARGEST_SIZE * 0.5)
    tf = tf.rotated(by: CGFloat(radians))
    tf = tf.translatedBy(x: LARGEST_SIZE * -0.5, y: LARGEST_SIZE * -0.5)
    context.concatenate(tf)
    context.draw(cgImage, in: drawRect)
    var rotatedImage = context.makeImage()!

    drawRect = drawRect.applying(tf)

    rotatedImage = rotatedImage.cropping(to: drawRect)!
    let resultImage = UIImage(cgImage: rotatedImage)
    return resultImage
  }
}

class Image {
  static let shared:Image = Image()
  var image:UIImage = UIImage(named:"Me")!
  var images:[UIImage] = []


  func shuffle(model:[Int], imageRef:UIImage) {
    image = imageRef
    images = self.slice(into: Int(sqrt(Double(model.count))))
  }

  func slice(into howMany: Int) -> [UIImage] {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .left, .leftMirrored:
      image = image.image(withRotation: (CGFloat)(Double.pi/2  ))
      break
    case .right, .rightMirrored:
      image = image.image(withRotation: (CGFloat)(-Double.pi/2))
      break
    default:
      break
    }
    width = image.size.width
    height = image.size.height

    let tileWidth = Int(width / CGFloat(howMany))
    let tileHeight = Int(height / CGFloat(howMany))

    let scale = Int(image.scale)
    var images = [UIImage]()
    let cgImage = image.cgImage!

    var adjustedHeight = tileHeight

    var y = 0
    for row in 0 ..< howMany {
      if row == (howMany - 1) {
        adjustedHeight = Int(height) - y
      }
      var adjustedWidth = tileWidth
      var x = 0
      for column in 0 ..< howMany {
        if column == (howMany - 1) {
          adjustedWidth = Int(width) - x
        }
        let origin = CGPoint(x: x * scale, y: y * scale)
        let size = CGSize(width: adjustedWidth * scale, height: adjustedHeight * scale)
        let tileCgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
        images.append(UIImage(cgImage: tileCgImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation))
        x += tileWidth
      }
      y += tileHeight
    }
    return images

  }
}
```

In case where howMany is bigger than 15, I get crashed, on real device only, with the following message:
"**Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue**"

Can anyone assist??

The only reason I could come up with is that the images created each time take to much space, as in case of 15 there will be 15^2 images = 225.

Even with that considered, I still can't think of a way I can do this differently..

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add code in loop to autoreleasepool.

```
autoreleasepool {
   if column == (howMany - 1) {
      adjustedWidth = Int(width) - x
   }
   let origin = CGPoint(x: x * scale, y: y * scale)
   let size = CGSize(width: adjustedWidth * scale, height: adjustedHeight * scale)
   let tileCgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
   images.append(UIImage(cgImage: tileCgImage!, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation))
x += tileWidth
}
```